# Only show one line on tr table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table like this:

[image: table]

and what I want is, to force the `<tr>` height to be fixed, change only when I hovered it, I won't see `<tr>` like red square on the picture.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Give your working code or put it in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to constrain the height to the inner `P` element and animate (or) toggle on `TR` hover

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hutan/1/edit?html,css,output)**

CSS:

```
.hoverRow td{
  background:#eee;
  vertical-align:top;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444;
}
.hoverRow p{   
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:1.3em;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}
.hoverRow tr:hover p{
  max-height:100px; /* don't exagerate :) */
}
```

HTML

```
  <table class="hoverRow">
    <tr>
      <td><p>Single line</p></td>
      <td><p>data</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Single line</p></td>
      <td><p>data</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          Multiple line<br>
          Multiple line<br>
          Multiple line
        </p>
      </td>
      <td><p>data</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Single line</p></td>
      <td><p>data</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your tr height on hover like below:

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;/* by default auto: by using fixed, it forces the layout as your height and width */
}
tr:hover{
  height: 200px; /* apply needed height*/
}
```

Comment: *as your height? ...*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry, what you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

If it is to keep `<tr>` `height` to match to 1 line you will need to set width of `<table>` and to few `<td>`s or `<th>`s  and fix these with `table-layout:fixed;`.

**next step is to set**  `tr`: `white-space:nowrap;` + `overflow:hidden;` (eventually `text-overflow:ellipsis;`.

**Then** on `tr:hover` reset `white-space` to normal , cells will extand to match content `height`.

Give us a fiddle , and *(i will*) add these rules to it .

Answer (score 0):

Apply text overflow for your td/tr. Here I add display:block. Because sometimes without this code doesn't work.

**[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri_shri/R6eZF/3/)**

**CSS Code:**

```
.youClass{
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
     width:100px;
  }

 .youClass:hover{
       white-space:normal;
       width:100px;
       word-wrap: normal;
       word-break:break-all;
  }
```

**Explanation:**

```
   yourText ='yourTextMore';
  `text-overflow:ellipsis` => `yourText...` => output(automatically add '...' at the end of the text)  
  `text-overflow:clip`     => `yourTextMor` => output('e' hide automatically)
```